# Why does setting `*\` to a scalar (string) reference not result in auto printing

Tags: perl

I've been recently playing around with [a Perl answer to a restricted-source code-challenge question on the Code Golf and Coding Challenges stack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271978/9365) and am stumped as to why some code that I expect to work, doesn't.

My example is trying to get output from a script when called with `-p0513`, but is equivalent:

```perl
*_=\"this works!";
print; # outputs `this works!`

*\=\"this doesn't work :(";
print; # outputs `this works!` without `$\`

print$\; # outputs `this doesn't work :(`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vc5BCsIwEIXhfU4xxoJSsKRINg3eJGCCBhqqSehMKF7eqAVBdOFK3/ZfvC@58SRLyehANq1ohGKs3u80p94jTHEccMEVS6MPpGAJMVPKhGBeumHwg6G9cP64PNvBASZ7cKzWT9kxOgwrmgXQrb8SYfLU3wuYSv/PO5sq/al645tSrjGRjwHLRsh2ewM)

I'm wondering why setting `*\` to a scalar reference (`\"..."`) results in `$\` not being correctly `print`ed after `$_`, when setting it naturally (e.g. `$\="test"`) does. `$_` being set the same way (e.g. `*_=\"test"`) doesn't seem to be affected.

I'm wondering if any Perl experts have any idea why this happens, and if there's a way I can use `*\=\"..."` (leaving me a free `_` to try and get a 7th output mechanism!)

Comment: `*\=\"this doesn't work :(";` doesn't assign anything to `$_`  but to ```$\``` (the output separator) so the value that was previously assigned to `$_` remains.

Comment: What do you mean by _"leaving me a free `_` to try and get a 7th output mechanism"_ btw? I've never lacked an output mechanism in perl. Using the special variables, like field separators, as storage just makes your code hard to read. `$_` is "bad" enough as it is.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Correct, but ``$\`` is printed after `$_` when not empty: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlYpJzM7VaEkI7NYyZqroCgzr8T6/38A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @TedLyngmo Code Golf is a game where you try to write a program in the fewest possible characters. Hard to read doesn't begin to describe it.

Comment: @DomHastings That example prints an uninitialized `$_` + the output separator. Use `strict` to avoid such code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo absolutely, this isn't "good" Perl in any sense of the word, but a challenge where, in this case, you cannot use any characters from your submission in any other subsequent submission, so in one answer I have `print'ni'`, in another `CORE::say musI|musa`, etc. I agree this code should be avoided in any non-recreational scenario.

Comment: Oh my, I stumbled into territory I care nothing about. Sorry :-) I'm out of here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking why

```bash
perl -e'local *\ = \"!\n"; print "";'
```

outputs nothing given that

```bash
perl -e'local $\ = "!\n"; print "";'
```

outputs `!␊`.

---

First, let's examine what `*x = \$y;` does.

`*x` is a typeglob, or glob for short. It's a symbol table entry. It's a structure that contains a number of pointers. One points to a scalar, one to an array, one to hash, one to sub, etc.

Absent a lexical (`my` or `our`) named `$x`,

```perl
$x
```

is equivalent to

```perl
${ *x{SCALAR} }
```

This means it accesses the scalar pointed by the scalar slot of the glob named `x`.

`*x = \$y;` sets that scalar to be `$y`, making these equivalent:

```perl
$x
```

```perl
${ *x{SCALAR} }
```

```perl
$y
```

---

If `local *\ = \"!\n";` makes `$\` equivalent to a scalar containing `!␊`, why doesn't the program output `!␊`?

Well, it must be that print doesn't use `$\`. And that is indeed the case.

Normally, `$\` is a magical variable.<sup>[1]</sup> Setting it causes an internal variable to be set. Reading it causes an internal variable to be read. This internal variable is what `print` uses.

You made it so `$\` accesses a literal constant instead of the magic variable. The internal variable was never changed. So the output of `print` is untouched.

---

1. ```
   $ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump( $\ )'
   SV = PVMG(0x55e7a72d00e0) at 0x55e7a728c2d0
     REFCNT = 1
     FLAGS = (GMG,SMG)       <-- Scalar has get magic & set magic
     IV = 0
     NV = 0
     PV = 0
     MAGIC = 0x55e7a729da30
       MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_sv
       MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_sv(\0)
       MG_OBJ = 0x55e7a728c240
       MG_LEN = 1
       MG_PTR = 0x55e7a72c4170 "\\"
   ```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for taking the time to clarify! `Devel::Peek` is new to me and clearly very useful! But I guess the TLDR is, ``$\`` is magic, `$_` isn't. Thank you so much!

Comment: `$_` is often aliased to another variable (e.g. by `for`), so it could be.